# Can a kong software works with windows?if yes then how?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, kong

I am trying installing kong software in my window system.Is it available for windows?Also cassandra is inbuild in it or i have to install separately.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should look the website...

https://getkong.org/install/

Apparently you can install using Docker.

Comment: Can we install Docker in Windows System??

Answer (score 1):

https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows

we can install Docker for Windows from here.